# How to prove that function doesn't take square values of natural numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve this task:

> Prove that function $f(n) = \lfloor{n + \sqrt(n) + \frac{1}{2} }\rfloor$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ takes all values except squares.

I calculated some values of the function:

$f(1)=2, f(2)=3, f(3)=5, f(4)=6, f(5)=7, f(6)=8, f(7)=10$ and so on.

I noticed I could rewrite the function as this:

$ f(n) = \lfloor{(n^{\frac{1}{2}} + \frac{1}{2})^{2} + \frac{1}{4}}\rfloor$

So it seems to be a bit bigger than a square number. However the fractional part of a square $(x^{\frac{1}{2}} + \frac{1}{2})^{2}$ seems to be around $.8...$ or $.9...$ so when we add $\frac{1}{4}$ the decimal part becomes $+1$ of what would be a square. For example, $\sqrt(3) + 3 + \frac{1}{4} = 4.98205081...$ so when I add $\frac{1}{4}$ it becomes $5.23205081$ and so $f(3)=5$.

I thought I could try to solve this through inequality:

$a^{2} + 1 - (x^{\frac{1}{2}} + \frac{1}{2})^{2} < \frac{1}{4}$,

where $a^{2}$ is the the number that I am not getting (for example $a^{2} = 4$ in case $n=3$). However, it didn't lead me anywhere.

I struggle to find some proof that would show why that happens. Could somebody give a hint?

Thanks in advance.